# OnDestroy being called WearableListenerService

Tags: android, android-service, wear-os

I am implementing an service inherited from wearablelistenerservice.

Its weird that the onDestroy method being called with the service is still running.  What should I do to avoid the ondestroy method being called?

thanks.

Comment: Could we perhaps see some code? Also Android is notorious for killing background services.

Comment: Generally speaking I wouldn't worry about it, it should be started again if you get a message. Also  don't use services to hold state information. :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you deferring some work to the background thread after receiving a callback in `WearableListenerService`? If yes, as soon as you leave the callback method scope, the service is a fair game and will be destroyed as soon as system decides so. The only guarantee (sort of) you are getting in WearableListenerService is that it will be kept alive in the scope of the callback method (unless there is a very strong memory pressure). If you need to do some background work, you start an `IntentService` from the `WearableListenerService`. However, it might be not necessary. `WearableListenerService` callback is already on a background thread, so you can do all the work you want. Just don't leave the method scope (no waiting for callbacks or launching `AsynTask`s; stick to blocking calls).

Comment: Im actually starting another separate thread to use audiorecord to read the microphone data. Do you think there is a better way to start a thread like that? Thanks.

Comment: When do you stop audiorecording? It seems that what you want is a separate service that will do the recording.